# DateDiff in LINQ

Tags: linq-to-sql

How I can find datediff in month using LINQ?

Comment: Consider changing the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the number of month boundaries crossed between two specific dates. You don't need LINQ for that; this should work:

```
// Assuming DateTime startDate, endDate
int monthDiff = ((endDate.Year - startDate.Year) * 12) + 
                (endDate.Month - startDate.Month);
```

Answer (score 29):

```
var result = from i in myTable 
             select SqlMethods.DateDiffMonth(i.DateStart, i.DateEnd);
```

This will generate sql query with `DATEDIFF` function