# convert datetime to milliseconds

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

i want convert a datetime variable in ASP.NET MVC to milliseconds,for example like to this:

'1288323623006'

which '1288323623006' in javascript with this format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z' means ' 2010-10-29 07:10:23 -3.530'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In javascript `getTime()` return the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01.

This link is answer for your question [DateTime to javascript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404247/datetime-to-javascript-date)

Comment: this answer is very good,
now i have a question:it is possible to convert a datetime to milliseconds which stored to database except now datetime?

Comment: If you are taking only about SQL function, you need sothing like [Convert MSSQL Timestamp/Datetime to Unix Timestamp](http://www.adamsdesk.com/be/archives/2011/05/17/how-to-convert-mssql-timestampdatetime-to-unix-timestamp/#axzz26XZC60l2)

Comment: no,i use entity framework code first and my field type is datetime.now i want fetch datetime which stored in database with Linq To Entity and convert that to milliseconds,now how i can do this?

Comment: Use last answer from this question: [DateDiff in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254417/datediff-in-linq). But you need another method, I didn't have VS now, find function yourself with intellisense.

Answer (score -1):

var d = new Date(your date);
then you can apply all the date functions on d
this should help.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

do you want to convert milliseconds to date or date to milliseconds?

Comment: date to milliseconds in ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Xmas95 = new Date("2010 10 29 07:10:23");
epoch = Xmas95.getTime()/1000;
alert(epoch);

Comment: Xmas95 = new Date("2010 10 29 07:10:23");
milli = Xmas95.getMilliseconds();
alert(milli)

Comment: this is incorrect.please read my questions,i said in question and in comment which i want convert date to milliseconds in ASP.NET MVC.

Admin,please give Warning to Srinivas Yedhuri.

Comment: i saw java-script tag in the question and gave you a java-script answer. i don't think the java-script answer is wrong. its better you edit the title of the question to "convert datetime to milliseconds in ASP.net MVC" to give more clarity.